# AWS Athena query hanging and re-reading data for huge query sizes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I set up a new log table in Athena in an S3 bucket that looks like below, where Athena is sitting on top of `BucketName/`

I had a well-functioning Athena system based on the same data but without the subdirectory structure listed below. Now with this new subdirectory structure I can see the data is properly displaying when I do `select * from table_name limit 100` but when I do something like `count(x) by week` the query hangs.

The data in S3 doesn't exceed 100GB in GZipped folders but the query was hanging for more than 20 minutes and said 6.5TB scanned, which sounds like it was looping and scanning over the same data. My guess is that it has to do with this directory structure but from what i've seen in other threads is that Athena should be able to parse through the subdirectories by just being pointed to the base folder `BucketName/`

`BucketName
|
|
|---Year(2016)
|       |
|       |---Month(11)
|       |      |
|       |      |---Daily File Format YYYY-MM-DD-Data000.gz`

Any advice would be appreciated!

Create Table DDL

`CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`test_table`(`
foo1`string,` 
foo2`string,` 
foo3`string,` 
date`string, 
  )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
  MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '\u0003' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'collection.delim'='\u0002') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://Listen_Data/2018/01'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  )`

Comment: please put entire query for better understanding.

Comment: Thanks @Dhaval, the issue isn't related to the query, it's happening with any query. I'm pretty sure it's related to the S3 directory structure and looking for how to resolve by changing Athena configuration to be able to scan the different daily files in the yearly / monthly folders as one database.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

`` PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `year` string, 
  `month` string) ``

after the schema definition in the DDL statement.